# Yml : Unable to validate load merged yml file

Tags: perl, yaml

I have merged two yml files with the help of following code.

```
use strict ;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all), NONFATAL => qw(exec);
use Cwd qw();
use Getopt::Long qw();
use YAML::XS qw(Load Dump);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
use Hash::Merge qw( merge );
Hash::Merge::set_behavior('RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT');
my($IN_YAML_1,$IN_YAML_2,$OUT_YAML) = undef;
($IN_YAML_1,$IN_YAML_2,$OUT_YAML) = @ARGV;
#reading 1st yaml file
my $in_yaml_1 = read_file($IN_YAML_1, { binmode => ':raw' });
my %in_hash_1 = %{ Load $in_yaml_1 };
#reading 2nd yaml file
my $in_yaml_2 = read_file($IN_YAML_2, { binmode => ':raw' });
my %in_hash_2 = %{ Load $in_yaml_2 };
#Merge hash_1 and hash_2
my %out_hash = %{ merge( \%in_hash_1, \%in_hash_2) };
open( FH, ">$OUT_YAML" ) or die "Can't open $OUT_YAML\n";
my $out_yaml = Dump \%out_hash;
write_file($OUT_YAML, { binmode => ':raw' }, $out_yaml);
close FH;
```

My yml files :-

one.yml

```
emailName: David
emailAddresses:
    - sillymoos@cpan.org
    - perltricks.com@gmail.com
credentials:
    username: sillymoose
    password: itsasecret
```

two.yml

```
emailName: Pranay
emailAddresses:
    - heelo@cpan.org
    - test@gmail.com
credentials:
    username: link
    password: sanity
```

### Output:

```
credentials:
  password:
  - itsasecret
  - sanity
  username:
  - sillymoose
  - link
emailAddresses:
- sillymoos@cpan.org
- perltricks.com@gmail.com
- heelo@cpan.org
- test@gmail.com
emailName:
- David
- Pranay
```

if we notice the order of the elements (`emailName` came last) in merged output.

Here while validating my merged yml file with against my yml schema.

```
eval { validate(YAML::LoadFile("Schema.yml"), YAML::LoadFile("merge.yml"))
```

It fails with error:

```
   YAML Error: Invalid element in map
   Code: YAML_LOAD_ERR_BAD_MAP_ELEMENT
   Line: 3
   Document: 1
```

Does change in order of elements causes this issue? How could i create my merge yml with same order it was present i.e. emailName: followed by emailAddresses: ...etc

Comment: Without knowing much about perl, the error is very likely that `emailName`, `password` and `username` contain scalars before the merge, but sequences afterwards. The order is no issue.

Comment: flyx, So even if order changes, You mean to say it wont be any issue during validation ?

Comment: Pretty sure. The YAML specification forbids key order to convey content information so any validator that depends on key order violates the spec. I don't know the one you're using though.

Comment: You're loading the YAML with [YAML.pm](https://metacpan.org/release/YAML), and the error message is a syntax error from YAML.pm, not a validation error. It looks like you are using a very old YAML.pm version which was not able to load zero-indented sequences. Why are you using YAML::XS for creating the file and YAML.pm for loading?

Comment: About the order: while in this case the order is no issue, if you want to preserve order, you might try [YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/release/YAML-PP) and look for `preserve`. Disclaimer: I'm the author ;-)

Comment: If i can able to preserve the order that would be great. Could you please provide example usage of the module to preserve the order.

Comment: @RAMA there is an example in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP). look for `PRESERVE_ORDER`. this is offtopic here and the comment box too small

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without seeing `Schema.yml`, but I'd guess it defines `username`, `password` and `emailName` as scalar values. After your merge, they are all lists of values. Your error says it happens on line 3 of the output file, and that's the first line that contains one of your new lists.

If you merge together two hashes, then you're almost certainly not going to get something that is the same shape as the two original hashes. So your schema validation is almost certain to fail, no matter how you merge the hashes.

We can't be much more help without knowing why you want to merge these files in this way and what you want to do with them afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure that if order of elements changes ...its schema validation fails ? Do we have any ready available tool over internet that creates schema from the given yml file?

Comment: @RAMA: *Are you sure that if order of elements changes ...its schema validation fails ?* No, I don't think that. And I've never said that I do.

Comment: I think i got the issue here is indentation problem.